# Trouble hooking up postgres to django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Following the documentation from [Django Postgres Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/databases/#postgresql-notes)I added to my settings.py

in settings I set

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'service': 'my_service',
            'passfile': '.my_pgpass',
        },
    }
}
```

Adjacent to settings.py I created pg_service.conf with

```
[my_service]
host=localhost
user=USER
dbname=NAME
port=5432
```

and adjacent to that I created mypg_pass

```
localhost:5432:PostgreSQL 14:postgres:LetMeIn
```

I am pretty sure I followed the documentation but on **python manage.py check** I got the following error.

```
 connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\oliver\base\correlator2v2\correlator2home\venv\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)django.db.utils.OperationalError: definition of service "my_service" not found
```

Answer (score 5):

> Adjacent to settings.py I created pg_service.conf

That is not where the system looks for it, see [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/libpq-pgservice.html)

"By default, the per-user service file is named ~/.pg_service.conf."  Where ~ refers to your home directory, not your current directory (and surely doesn't refer to 'the same directory where settings.py is located', since PostgreSQL doesn't even know what that file is)

Comment: This is the preferred method so that production psql creds are not leaked into git or other places you don't want the creds to appear. Edit: Would also be good if Django docs directly cited the home dir location at OP's link as that's where people are looking when setting up their projects.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to add the .pg_service.conf to the **user home directory.**

The .pgpass file has to be in the Django project root directory (where the manage.py is)

Answer (score 1):

It is not able to find the service, but actually one is not required to use the service at all...

OP can simply

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'NAME', # database name
        'USER': 'USER',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd caution against using this method outside of isolated test and dev environments, esp if the project is in a git as it'll expose the psql credentials.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got it working (Django 4.2) with psycopg3.1.9:

```
# settings.py

DATABASES = {
        "default": {
            "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
            "OPTIONS": {
                "service": "my_service",
                "passfile": ".my_pgpass",
            },
        }
    }
```

And create .pg_service.conf at `~`:

```
# ~/.pg_service.conf

[my_service]
host=localhost
user=USER
dbname=DBNAME
port=5432
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the error as well

```
**conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)**
```

django.db.utils.OperationalError: definition of service "Servers" not found
I follow two fectors:

1.I create the file ".pg_service.conf" in %APPDATA%, and I wrote database information, like this

```
[Servers]
host=localhost
user=wingto
dbname=HyCloud
port=5432
```

2.create passfile in nearby my django project, manage.py
[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0hYO.png

3.in django

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        "OPTIONS": {
                "service": "Servers",
                "passfile": "passfile",
            },
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34655058)

Answer (score 0):

Step 1> Check Version Compatibility [Python 3.9.6, Django 4.2, psycopg2 2.9.9, postgreSQL admin >= 12]

Step 2> Create [.pg_service.conf] file with given below variables with keys as given below and values as given in PostgreSQL

```
[my_service] 
host=localhost 
port=5433 
dbname=postgres 
user=postgres 
password=1234567
```

Step 3> set actual path of above .pg_service.conf file in windows/ubuntu as given in below examples.

```
windows CMD> set PGSERVICEFILE=D:\User\kparmar\Downloads\DJANGO\mysite\.pg_service.conf 

ubuntu CMD> export PGSERVICEFILE=D:\User\kparmar\Downloads\DJANGO\mysite\.pg_service.conf
```

Step 4> Set above configured details in [settings.py]

```
DATABASES = { 
    "default": { 
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql", 
        "OPTIONS": { 
            "service": "my_service" 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Step 5> The Details given in Django4.2 official document are incorrect for postgres configuration.