# PostgreSQL connection settings got error in Django

Tags: django, postgresql

I read the new version in [django document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/databases/#postgresql-notes), I am follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73633619/trouble-hooking-up-postgres-to-django/76636109#76636109) , but doesn't work:

```
**conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)**
django.db.utils.OperationalError: definition of service "Servers" not found
```

here is my processing:
1.I create the file ".pg_service.conf" in %APPDATA%, and I wrote database information, like this:

```
[Servers]
host=localhost
user=wingto
dbname=HyCloud
port=5432
```

2.create passfile in nearby my django project, manage.py
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSNyD.png)

```
localhost:5432:HyCloud:wingto:*****
```

3.Setting.py in django

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        "OPTIONS": {
                "service": "Servers",
                "passfile": "passfile",
            },
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have given the wrong file extension your file should start with '.passfile' and it should be inside the project folder. please save your file with '.passfile' don't use .conf

```
DATABASES = {
"default": {
    "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
    "OPTIONS": {
            "service": "Servers",
            "passfile": ".passfile",
        },
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to PostgreSQL documentation, it's suggested to create your `pg_service.conf` and `pgpass.conf` inside the `%APPDATA%\postgresql\` like this `%APPDATA%\postgresql\.pg_service.conf` and the password file `%APPDATA%\postgresql\pgpass.conf`.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgservice.html
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html